# If two sublists's components in a list have equal value max(list, key=itemgetter[7]) returns only the one

Tags: python

I'm using `python v2.7` and I have a list that contains 4 lists. In the `list_720` I want to keep  the list with the highest score. The score is the last item `list_720[7]` of each sublist. Here two sublists have the same score 6.5. In that case I want to keep the one having the maximum `list_720[3]`

```
from operator import itemgetter

list_720 = [
    ['encoding_txt\\pirkagia_10b_720x576_15_qp_22_ON_encoder_randomaccess_B16_Filters_ON_scalable_JOURNAL2017.txt',
        '720x576', 22, 39.9292, 1995.6394, 5014.911, 10.183, 5.5],
    ['encoding_txt\\pirkagia_10b_720x576_15_qp_20_ON_encoder_randomaccess_B16_Filters_ON_scalable_JOURNAL2017.txt',
        '720x576', 20, 41.5031, 3072.097, 5639.054, 11.604, 5.5],
    ['encoding_txt\\pirkagia_10b_720x576_25_qp_22_ON_encoder_randomaccess_B16_Filters_ON_scalable_JOURNAL2017.txt',
        '720x576', 22, 39.9292, 3326.0656, 4981.942, 10.264, 6.5],
    ['encoding_txt\\pirkagia_10b_720x576_25_qp_20_ON_encoder_randomaccess_B16_Filters_ON_scalable_JOURNAL2017.txt',
        '720x576', 20, 41.5031, 5120.1616, 5589.295, 11.265, 6.5],
]
```

Using `max(list_720, key=itemgetter(7))` I get only the first sublist that has the highest score which is not correct.

Is there a simple way to select based on `list_720[3]` value?

Comment: you mean `max(list_720, key=lambda x : (x.itemgetter(7),x.itemgetter(2))` ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I think that's just `x.itemgetter(7,2)`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Using your code I get 'SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg'

Comment: you probably want max for 7th item but then min for 2nd item from your comment of Moses answer. Please [edit] to explain

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I had wrong index `list_720[2]`. The correct one is `list_720[3]`. Moses answer is correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the index 3 to `itemgetter` to break ties:

```
max(list_720, key=itemgetter(7, 3))
```

Comment: Thank you! It's correct! Just change `(7,2)` to `(7,3)` since I had wrong item's index.